# Getting selected item from combobox itemrenderer and storing in object

Tags: flex3

I have a combo box itemrenderer in datagrid column. I want to get the user selected item from the dropdown of the row(s) (User may select values from combo box from multiple rows of datagrid) and corresponding values of all other columns of the rows and store it in an object . Then pass this object to database to update only those rows that user has changed.

I am able to get the selected item from combo box using "event.currentTarget.selectedItem" and corresponding values of all other columns of the rows using "valueSelect.ID", etc where valueSelect is object which contains data for datagrid. But am stuck with, how to store the selected item value of the combobox and corresponding values of all other columns of the rows into an Object?

I am seeking sample code to store selected item from combobox and its corresponding values of all other columns into an object which I can send to db.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flex, you can bind the selectedItem property / object of the DataGrid to an Object (of the "type" used to render the ItemRenderer).

Or you can do it manually, store a reference to that object by declaring an Object (or some specific type) and then updating that value whenever a selection occurs.

So for example :

```
[Bindable]public var selectedItem:Object;
...
public function onComboBoxChanged(evt:ListEvent):void
{
    selectedItem = dataGrid.selectedItem;
    ...
    // comboBox specific logic here
    ...
}
```

That or, if you need something complex, possibly check out this post for a custom item renderer :

[Flex DataGrid with ComboBox itemRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408729/flex-datagrid-with-combobox-itemrenderer)

Hope that helps!